# return linq result via web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to use Linq in a webservice that returns a data from a query. As
the data return from Linq to Sql is IEnumerable and it's not possible to
easily get a Dataset.what is the best format to return data?

```
 DataClassesDataContext Dac = new DataClassesDataContext();
        Dac.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionCs"].ConnectionString;
       var query = from record in Dac.RetrieveWorkshops(WorkshopCode, Name)  select  record;
```

Answer (score 0):

Web-service proxies instantiate collections as arrays, so I've gotten into the habit of defining 'data transfer objects' and returning IEnumerable's of those DTO's. In your case, You could define a WorkshopDTO object which contained only the public properties you wanted to return and have your LINQ query construct them based on each record it reads. Then your client-proxy will see an array of WorkshopDTO's to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your data into an object and return a list of that object in Web Service.

Example:

```
public class WorkshopEntity
{
     string Name { get; set; }
     string Location { get; set; }
}

List<WorkshopEntity> workshopList = (from record in Dac.RetrieveWorkshops(WorkshopCode, Name)  select new WorkshopEntity { Name=record.name, Location=record.Location }).ToList();
```

Comment: so how can  client use webmethod output?

Comment: The consumer of the web service will access that object due to serialization. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
return query.ToArray();
```

but remember to add `[Serializable]` Attribiute at top of your `WorkshopEntity` class.

if your have complex type properties in `WorkshopEntity` inform me because you should do more.